# How to query Firestore and write to sqflite database on every auth change before allowing the user to continue using the app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I have a wrapper widget that checks the auth changes and either returns the authenticate widget (for users to sign up/log in) or the home screen (first screen the user sees after logging in). On every auth change, it returns either the Firebase auth uid or null. This is pretty standard.

In the rest of my app, I need to use the uid and the user's username for various queries and to display on some screens throughout the rest of the app. The username must be queried from Firestore using the uid. How would I do this properly? This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

1. Create a provider to hold global variables `currentUID` and `currentUsername`
2. Create a database using sqflite (so I can store the `currentUsername` and not have to requery Firestore on every app startup)
3. On every auth change, query Firestore for the username, write these values to the database, then update the global variables

**auth.dart:**

```
  // create CurrentUser object based on Firebase user object
  UserModel.ModelAuthUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return UserModel.ModelAuthUser(uid: user.uid);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<UserModel.ModelAuthUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }
```

**wrapper.dart:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ModelAuthUser?>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
          final globals = context.read<GlobalsProvider>();
          if (value?.uid == null) {
            db.sqlDeleteAllRows(db: localDB, table: StaticGlobals.sqlTableName);
            globals.updateCurrentUIDUsername(uid: '', username: '');
            return const Authenticate();
          } else {
            String currentUsername;
            currentUsername = db.sqlGetCurrentUsername(); //ERROR: A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'
            if (currentUsername == '') {
              currentUsername = db.getCurrentUsernameFS(currentUID: value!.uid);
            }
            db.sqlWriteCurrentUIDUsername(uid: value!.uid, username: currentUsername);
            globals.updateCurrentUIDUsername(uid: value!.uid, username: currentUsername); //ERROR: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
            return const Home();
          }
        },
    );
  }
```

The code in wrapper.dart doesn't work because `db.sqlDeleteAllRows`, `db.sqlGetCurrentUsername`, and `db.sqlWriteCurrentUIDUsername` are all asynchronous operations that return a Future and I can't add async/await to wrapper.dart because it gives an error: `The argument type 'Future<StatefulWidget> Function(BuildContext, ModelAuthUser?, Widget?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, ModelAuthUser?, Widget?)'`

The other problem is that when I do `globals.updateCurrentUIDUsername` in wrapper.dart, I get the error `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build` (tagged the line above where this error points to).

What am I doing wrong? I feel as though this should be a normal thing that most Flutter developers need to do in a moderately advanced app, but I can't figure out how to do it. I just want to run 1 function to check for Firebase auth changes, then update a database & provider with some values, and then allow the user to use the app. This seems like it should be a very basic thing in Flutter development, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Comment: If you're loading an asynchronous value, use a `FutureBuilder` to unwrap it.